# .map array of object titles into a new array based on number of votes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I have an array of object that looks something like this.

```
array = [
  {
    title: Title1,
    votes: 2,
  },
  {
    title: Title2,
    votes: 1,
  },
  {
    title: Title3,
    votes: 1,
  },
];
```

What I am trying to do is use .map to push the titles into a new array, but based on the number of votes that object has.

For this example, it would look like this.

```
newArray = [Title1, Title1, Title2, Title3]
```

Is using .map the best way to go with this as I am working with React.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not the best for this. It is useful when you want a new array that is the same length as the original array. You can achieve what you want to do with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const array = [ { title: 'Title1', votes: 2 }, { title: 'Title2', votes: 1 }, { title: 'Title3', votes: 1 } ];

const result = array.reduce( (res, el) => res.concat( Array( el.votes ).fill( el.title ) ), [] );

console.log( result );
```

There is also currently a [proposal for an Array.prototype.flatMap](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/#sec-Array.prototype.flatMap) function which works very nicely for your case, but doesn't have much browser support yet:

```js
const array = [ { title: 'Title1', votes: 2 }, { title: 'Title2', votes: 1 }, { title: 'Title3', votes: 1 } ];

const result = array.flatMap( el => Array( el.votes ).fill( el.title ) );

console.log( result );
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking to do with this.

And thanks for the info on the additional array function, I will have to check that out.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by taking the `votes` as count for a while loop for pushing `title`.

```js
var array = [{ title: 'Title1', votes: 2 }, { title: 'Title2', votes: 1 }, { title: 'Title3', votes: 1 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { title, votes }) => {
        while (votes--) r.push(title);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` with `concat` methods and spread syntax.

```js
let array = [ { title: 'Title1', votes: 2 }, { title: 'Title2', votes: 1 }, { title: 'Title3', votes: 1 } ];
let result = [].concat(...array.map(({title, votes}) => Array(votes).fill(title)));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` only returns one value per element. You probably want something like `Array.reduce`:

```
let newArray = array.reduce((accum, curValue) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < curValue.votes; i++) {
    accum.push(curValue.title);
  }
  return accum;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine map with fill with concat like this:

```
Array.prototype.concat(...array.map(elem => new Array(elem.votes).fill(elem.title)))
```

result

```
["Title1", "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use array.sort() first and than array.map() to return only the desired property like this (original array stays intact, not mutated):

```
var array = [{ title: 'Title1', votes: 2 }, { title: 'Title2', votes: 1 }, { title: Title3', votes: 1 }];

const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.votes > b.votes).map((item) => item.title)

console.log(result)
```

Titles with the same amount of votes are sorted lexiographically.